# Why are conflict markers created the way they are and why does merging work the way does?

Tags: git, merge

I've been learning about git and while I think I have an idea of how conflict resolution and merging works, I'm wondering why the way it's done (at least by default, when simply using `git merge`) is sensible.

There's situations where the whole merge will be done automatically, and yet it's not quite clear to me that it's the right thing to do. For example, suppose I have a base commit `base` and two 'child' commits `A, B` of `base`. If `A` adds some functionality to some function `f` defined in `base` and meanwhile `B` creates a function `g` with the assumption that `f` functions a certain way, it certainly seems like `g` might fail - and yet git merge might very well be done automatically. Even if it's not done automatically, no sort of conflict markers might be made.

Not even something like adding files is completely safe. A newly added file could contain functionality that makes assumptions on the already existing files. A script that goes through all files in the folder and does some parsing is something I can think of - it might work, but a new file that has a weird character that does not get parsed properly will cause issues.

But maybe these types of problems could be classified in some way? Perhaps it could be said that the primary goal of 'correct' merge is that the program still compiles correctly, but there's no guarantee that it will function properly or give a reasonable result. I'm not an experienced programmer, and I don't really even know how to properly define a 'proper' program.

//

Regardless, I don't really understand why merging is done the way it is, and why I could possibly rely on just running a `git merge` and only going through merge conflict markers. Perhaps in some specific type of a language, but generally, it doesn't make sense to me. I would think that for a merge to make sense, you should roughly do some type of recursive check - essentially, if you have a new function in one commit, you should check all its dependancies for any modifications in the other commit. Ignoring whether that's even feasible (I doubt that), I might be missing something and such a recursive check might not be necessary.

I'd appreciate some type of in-depth explanation of what the reasoning is behind the way it's done and why it makes sense. I've done some googling but I'm not sure what this topic is called - I'd definitely appreciate a reference to some in-depth explanation that deals with this topic in a more formal and precise way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `git merge` is to take these textual changes, and combine them with those textual changes, as much as possible.

If the semantics of those textual changes are not compatible, then you should not be doing `git merge` in the first place. That's your job, as the programmer, to make sure what your doing makes sense. And if you have good test suites in place, it's their job to flag to you that the merge broke something.

But as far as Git is concerned, it's going what you asked, and it's doing it correctly (most of the time).

Comment: Under which circumstances can you know that the textual changes are compatible though? If you have to go through both the commits and check that they are in some sense compatible, why not actually merge them together manually, while you're already doing that? What use is `git merge` if you'll go through the code yourself anyway.

Comment: Well, going through the merges manually can be a lot of work. The automated tools I recommend for compatibility checking is good unit testing. If you wrote good tests, hopefully one will fail when you merge something that is semantically incompatible.

Comment: I've been using Git and its merging capabilities from many years now, and from experience it's rarely been a problem. The only issues I've had were actually textual merging errors: function `f()` was added in both branches, but not exactly in the same place, and git merge kept two copies of `f()` in the results. I've had this happen two or three times in 10 years or so. I don't recall ever encountering a case like you're describing that was not caught by unit testing. So I trust git merges that don't fail unit testing.

Comment: And, I should add: for the textual change errors I mention, at least once, code failed because `f()` was defined twice, so I was able to catch it in the process. And at least once I remember only noticing the problem months later. Pretty darn good batting average for the thousands of git merges (and related operations) I've done over the years.

Comment: @Jake1234 *Under which circumstances can you know that the textual changes are compatible?* If you merge two branches, you absolutely *have* to understand both sides of the merge. If you do not, or if you are unable to verify the correctness of the merge, you are not the right person to do that particular merge. Relying only on the absence of textual conflicts is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This question itself is not a good fit for StackOverflow.  It's not clear to me where it *should* go though ([SoftwareEngineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)? [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)?).  I've been away from academia long enough<sup>1</sup> that I don't know who's doing what kind of research on diff-and-merge problems at this point.  It does look like a phrase you may want is *structured merge tools:* see, e.g., [this paper](https://www.se.cs.uni-saarland.de/publications/docs/CBS+19.pdf).

> Regardless, I don't really understand why merging is done the way it is ...

There are some historical reasons—in particular, the old string-to-string edit problem was, pretty early on, turned into line-by-line difference tooling—and there's the purely practical fact that, for a lot of cases, it *really works*.

You might concentrate here on cases where we see that it really *doesn't* work.  For instance, Git's line-by-line approach generally fails miserably with XML text.  Yet there don't seem to be good XML merge tools, suggesting that this problem is hard, rare, or both.

I do argue that blindly trusting `git merge` is a bad idea.  That's why we have things like unit and component tests.  But this is a topic for the SoftwareEngineering site, not for StackOverflow.

---

<sup>1</sup>Approximately two decades now, yikes.